# Algorithm design for CodeChef - Our Base is Under Attack

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge

I was working on a CodeChef challenge: [Our Base is Under Attack](https://www.codechef.com/problems/BASE). I have a working solution but it is not fast enough. Could you recommend anything to make it faster?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class BaseAttack {
private static Map<long[], Integer> powerMaps = new HashMap<>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int testCases;
    testCases = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());

    for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++){
        long number;
        number = Long.valueOf(in.readLine());
        if(number == 1L){
            System.out.println("INFINITY");
            continue;
        }
        if(number == 0L){
            System.out.println("0");
            continue;
        }
        if(number == 2l){
            System.out.println("1");
            continue;
        }
        if(number == 3l){
            System.out.println("2");
            continue;
        }
        long half = number / 2;
        long count = 1L + (number -half);
        for (long base = 3; base <= half; base++){
            long bound = base;
            while(true){
                if(number >= bound){
                    if(2* bound > number){
                       count++;
                       break;
                    }else{
                        bound *= base;
                    }
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Given that `N` can be \$10^{12}\$, your main loop can iterate up to \$5*10^{11}\$ times.  You were able to set your count immediately to `1L + (number - half)`.  How were you able to do that?  Can you see how you can do that again to find other solutions?

Comment: In base 2 every number starts with 1 (so I can start my count with 1). If N is given and I change the base to X > N/2 (and X < N) than the result will start with 1 (N / X  = 1.someDigits).

Comment: Correct.  Now consider three digit numbers in base B of the form 1xx.  The range of values for 1xx in base B is `[B^2 ... 2*B^2)`.  How can you use this fact the same way you did "X > N/2 and X < N"?  Hint: `B^2 <= N < 2*B^2` from the range above.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to add a short summary of the problem statement?  You can keep the link as a reference, but your question does need to be complete even if the linked material isn't accessible.  Thanks.